# How is max width being set on this site?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This site: http://www.samuelgrant.co.uk

This is exactly the kind of setup I want to build. I'm stuck, however, at figuring out how the maximum width of this site is being set. I want a centered main content area like this site has with the background stretching to full browser width. Can anyone enlighten me? Relative newbie here...any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's a clue if you View/Source.  It says in a comment: *THE RESPONSIVE GRID SYSTEM
Taken from http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/*

Comment: yes, that's the same grid I'm using...in the CSS, however, there is no max width set that I can see... the outer wrap is specified at 100% and all the stuff inside of it is calculated with percentages. I still don't see how the max width is being determined and why the entire site doesn't just stretch to fill the window.

Comment: `width:100%` stretches to full browser width and `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;` aligns content area to centered.

Comment: I see several CSS definitions for `max-width: 72em;`. See the definition for `.inner` in `samuelgrant.css` line 454.

Comment: ahhhhh ems, not px...thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-w">
        Stuff in your inner column
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: #f06;
}

.container .inner-w {
    max-width: 50em; /* or 400px etc */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

[a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/yD8Wg/) that also shows this column width - and how it can be different in each sections etc.